# Enable versioning for a bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, illegalargumentexception

While trying to enable versioning for the bucket:

```
$r = $s3Client->putBucketVersioning(array(
            'Bucket' => 'test-bucket-pcloud',
            'Status' => 'Enabled'   
));
```

I get `InvalidArgumentException`. What could be the reason for it? Do I also need to supply the other 2 arguments as [listed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketVersioning)? I am not really clear what role does `MFA` and `MFADelete` play.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you also need to supply the `MFADelete` and `Status` arguments.

[MFA Delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMFADelete.html) is a way of preventing objects from being deleted from Amazon S3 unless a multi-factor authentication code is provided.

For your situation, use: `'MFADelete' => 'Disabled', 'Status' => 'Enabled'`